# Outlook 2016 suddenly asking for password but won't accept it

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I have a windows 10 workstation that suddenly started asking for my outlook password.  It is an O365 on a windows network.  I have tried to reinstall, remove, delete credentials, etc to no success.  It isn't a password issue.  I can access outlook with the same account on another device not on the network or at Office online without issue.  Any ideas?  My next thought was to remove the computer from the domain or to delete the device from Azure AD.  I am open to any help.

Comment: Try adding another Outlook profile for the same account to determine if it's a profile problem.

Comment: Are you IT or do you have IT?

Comment: We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go in and get it to delete the work account in settings and I cleared everything from the credentials manager.  After doing these two items, I was finally able to add the account to outlook.Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Heres a few things you could try if you already haven't.

1. Clear cached passwords.
2. Verify that prompt for Credentials isn’t checked in profile.
3. Turn off Outlook Anywhere – don’t do this if this is a laptop that connects to email 
   without using the VPN software.

Another thing that you might want to check is the licensing on the account.